# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException.class

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-multidex

I am getting error like this when i run the application.I am using HttpClient,HttpEntity,HttpResponse and HttpPost in my MainActivity..so i made some modifications to gradle file.After that i am getting error like this.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException.class
```

i have also included multidex library and org.apache.http.legacy.jar in my app.but then also i am getting the same error.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
}
```

I Know this question has been asked many times,but none of the solutions worked for me..
Can anyone please help me to resolve this one.

Comment: You are adding this class org/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException twice. Check your dependencies.

Comment: I checked..i have added only once..and even i commented            `compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')` this line in dependencies because i have copied the jar file in libs folder..But then also i am getting same error.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti what might be the issue..?

Answer (score 0):

You may not use "compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'" nor "compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')" at the same time.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What would be the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. The problem is Since you are using

```
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar') and
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
```

You need to remove the two libs which I mentioned below. Which contains duplication of the above.

```
if you are adding legacy and httpmime you don't need this
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'//remove this
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5' // remove this too
```

Also add this inside android section in gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```